# Why class method are not accessible in Extension Method while using IEnumerator class List

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, ienumerable

This my Generic Class

```
public class CustomClass<T>
    {
        public T Data { set; get; }
        public T getData()
        {
            return Data;
        }
    }
```

This is my Main Method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            mylist = new List<CustomClass<int>>();
            CustomClass<int> customClass = new CustomClass<int>();
            customClass.Data = 10;
            CustomClass<int> customClass1 = new CustomClass<int>();
            customClass1.Data = 10;
            mylist.Add(customClass);
            mylist.Add(customClass1);
            CustomClass<int> custom = new CustomClass<int>();
            custom.Data = 20;
            mylist.Add(custom);
            Console.WriteLine(mylist[0].getData());
            Console.WriteLine("----------All----------");
            Console.WriteLine(value: mylist.CustomAll('%', 3, AllAny));
            }
```

This is Extension where I want to recieve the Data of Custom Class but It is showing error

```
public static class CustomOperation
    {

        public static bool CustomAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, char symbol, int compare, Action<List<T>, int, char, bool> func)
        {
            e[0].Data// Error here I want CustomClass Data
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your extension method is also available on `List<string>`, as well as `List<string>` (any kind of `List`, in fact):

```
// This compiles!
var intList = new List<int> {1,2,3};
intList.CustomAll('a', 0, (a,b,c,d) => {});
```

`e[0]` would then be an `int`, so what would `e[0].Data` be? `int` doesn't have a member called `Data`!

And that's not the only problem, it would also be available on any `IEnumerable`. Not all `IEnumerable` can be indexed with an `int`, so `e[0]` doesn't always make sense.

This is why your code doesn't make a lot of sense. You need to constrain it to work only on `IList<CustomClass<T>>`, or even more specifically, `IList<CustomClass<int>>` if you want `Data` to be an `int`:

```
public static bool CustomAll<T>(this IList<CustomClass<T>> e, char symbol, int compare, Action<List<CustomClass<T>>, int, char, bool> func)
// or
public static bool CustomAll(this IList<CustomClass<int>> e, char symbol, int compare, Action<List<CustomClass<int>>, int, char, bool> func)
```

If you want it to work on all `IEnumerable<CustomClass<T>>`, then you need to use `e.First()` rather than `e[0]` (among other things). I can't tell you exactly how to write this without knowing the implementation of `CustomAll`.